# two quesrystring in href of <a>

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to put "&" with second querystring in HTML  in .aspx design. when I type "&" in href HTML , Visual studio start hilighting as error. what could be the solution to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&amp;` instead of `&`. For example:

```
<a href="http://example.com?foo=bar&amp;bar=baz">Foo</a>
```